# How to type cast webbrowsercontrolobj.document to mshtml.HTMLDocument VB6? or How to submit form loaded in webbrowser control in vb6?

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, mshtml

Hello I am writing code in VB6 only **(no VB.NET)**

I have webbrowsercontrol object named webbrowser1
I have added reference of **microsoft html object library** in project.

I am trying this line but is giving error.

```
Dim doc as MSHTML.HTMLDocument
doc = DirectCast(webbrowser1.document, MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
```

line 2 is giving error that no method or data found at MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Please help me solving this problem.

What I want is I have one webpage having 2 (html forms) in it. I am loading that page into
webbrowser control by,

```
webbrowser1.navigate "url"
```

I have mapped event to handle html button click in webbrowser1's document.
**When user clicks on this button I want to submit second form of html page.
Is there any other way to do it?**

I also tried following code

```
'this line is working properly
'this is the code to submit first form in html page
webbrowser1.document.Forms(0).submit
```

but when I do

```
'this line is giving error though there are 2 forms available in html page
webbrowser1.document.Forms(1).submit
```

So ultimate goal is to submit second form of html document.
Please show me right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just direct assignment?

```
Dim doc as MSHTML.HTMLDocument 
Set doc = webbrowser1.document
```

VB6 doesn't really do casting, but you can access any method (early bound) by assigning it to an variable of the required type, or (late bound) by blindly using a variable of `Object` type.

Comment: I tried this code but failed to compile code

Dim objMSHTML As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set objMSHTML = webbrowser1.Document

It gives error object needed error no 424

Comment: @mitesh why did you accept the answer if it doesnt answer your question? i have the answer to your question, will provide an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Dim doc as MSHTML.HTMLDocument to Dim doc as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument.

Notice the IHTMLDocument has an I at the start, then try to submit the form.

Also, there is no such thing as DirectCast in VB6 - that is only a VB.NET thing.

So just do this:

```
Dim doc as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument

Set doc = webbrowser1.document
```

Now you will get intellisense on doc.  :)

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: You're missing a `Set`. it will fail with "Object not set"